# Robot Framework - Focus/Select DropDown popup window

Tags: user-interface, testing, popup, robotframework, dropdown

I have a requirement to write a UI test using Robot Framework. I am simulating user login in this website https://www.cosmote.gr/hub/ (select English on the top right of the webpage). User should click on Login/Register and a popup window appears:

[popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ns9y.png)

I am trying now to add input text in email text field as well as in password field and then pressing the button to login. Since I am new to Robot Framework, I am not aware how to focus in the popup window and therefore my test are failing - it cannot find the text field in the popup window.

[login example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbWP9.png)

My code is:

```
    *** Settings ***
Documentation    Present some information about this test suite
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Browser} =  ff
${HOME_PAGE} =  https://www.cosmote.gr/hub/
${BUTTON_LOGIN} =  //*[@id="wcs_header"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
${VALID_USERNAME} =  
${VALID_PASSWORD} =  
${PAGE_CONTAINS} =  My COSMOTE
${USERNAME_FIELD} =  //*[@id="loginIn"]
${PASSWORD_FIELD} =  //*[@id="pwdIn"]
${SUBMIT_BUTTON} =  //*[@id="loginBtnIn"]
${POPUP} =  //*[@id="cosid_md_login"]/div[2]
${FRAME} =  idmframeIn

*** Test Cases ***
User Login With Valid Credentials
    [Tags]  Login
    Open Browser  ${HOME_PAGE}  ${Browser}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${BUTTON_LOGIN}
    Click Element  ${BUTTON_LOGIN}
    Wait Until Page Contains  ${PAGE_CONTAINS}
    Select Frame  id=${FRAME}
    Input text  ${USERNAME_FIELD}  ${VALID_USERNAME}
    Input password  ${PASSWORD_FIELD}  ${VALID_PASSWORD}
    Click Element  ${SUBMIT_BUTTON}
    Wait Until Page Contains  Hello
    Close Browser
```

How can I focus/select the popup window in order to find the text fields and the login button elemenets?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This looks like it should work. What happens when you run the test? Do you get a failure message? What is the message?

Comment: @BryanOakley I get this error message :"Element with locator '//*[@id="loginIn"]' not found". I believe that this happens because it is not focused on the popup and therefore it cannot find the xpath of the textfield, but I am not sure (and I do not know how to focus on the popup, I tried with the Select Frame but it does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running your example I noticed that the window is not expanding to maximum size. This may cause the search bar and the link to overlap. When I added the `Maximize Browser Window` keyword that solved that particular issue.

As the `Select Frame` was causing issues, and there is no need for it, removed it from the script.

The below script runs and fills in the values. As the username and password are not valid the final check doesn't pass due to a failed login. However, that is expected.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Present some information about this test suite
Library  Selenium2Library

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${Browser} =  chrome
${HOME_PAGE} =  https://www.cosmote.gr/hub/
# ${BUTTON_LOGIN} =  //*[@id="wcs_header"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
${BUTTON_LOGIN} =  id=cosid_md_login
${VALID_USERNAME} =  dummy
${VALID_PASSWORD} =  dummy
${PAGE_CONTAINS} =  My COSMOTE
${USERNAME_FIELD} =  //*[@id="loginIn"]
${PASSWORD_FIELD} =  //*[@id="pwdIn"]
${SUBMIT_BUTTON} =  //*[@id="loginBtnIn"]
#${FRAME} =  idmframeIn

*** Test Cases ***
User Login With Valid Credentials
    [Tags]  Login
    Open Browser  ${HOME_PAGE}  ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${BUTTON_LOGIN}
    Click Element  ${BUTTON_LOGIN}
    Wait Until Page Contains  ${PAGE_CONTAINS}
    # Select Frame  id=${FRAME}
    Input Text    ${USERNAME_FIELD}  ${VALID_USERNAME}
    Input password  ${PASSWORD_FIELD}  ${VALID_PASSWORD}
    Click Element  ${SUBMIT_BUTTON}
    Wait Until Page Contains  Hello
    Close Browser
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, it worked fine. I have also tried to fix this issue by removing Select Frame and I have replaced it with Focus (which worked), however it is unecessary since your code works without need to focus on the popup.